# How to limit item in the cart for each category in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I have a visual images,
First click add-to-cart button, check validation of qty allowance for each category, output error message on top of the cart widget.
How do i count product in each cateogy in cart with woocommerce?
Thanks in advance

```
public function check_product_in_cart($product_in_cart) {
            //Check to see if user has product in cart
            global $woocommerce;

            // start of the loop that fetches the cart items

            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];

                $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

                // second level loop search, in case some items have several categories
                // this is where I started editing Guillaume's code

                $cat_ids = array();

                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $cat_ids[] = $term->term_id;
                }

                if(in_array(70, (array)$cat_ids) ||in_array(69, (array)$cat_ids) || in_array(68, (array)$cat_ids)) {
                    //if exist in "strain" category 

                    //output true

                   $product_in_cart = true;
                   //how to count all item in this category??? Thanks
                }

            }

            return $product_in_cart;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how I got it, count the quantity of the category inside the cart item. First looking if there are any item in the cart belong to that category, if found, get the quantity of that item and output the category count. Work with every single category.

```
    public function check_product_in_cart($product_in_cart) {
        //Check to see if user has product in cart
        global $woocommerce;

        // start of the loop that fetches the cart items
        $aty = 0;
        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];

            $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

            // second level loop search, in case some items have several categories
            // this is where I started editing Guillaume's code

            $cat_ids = array();

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $cat_ids[] = $term->term_id;
            }

            if(in_array(70, (array)$cat_ids) ||in_array(69, (array)$cat_ids) || in_array(68, (array)$cat_ids)) {//popular

              //category is in cart!

               $product_in_cart = true;
               $product_catqty = $values['quantity'];//get the quantiy of the item
               $aty += $product_catqty;
            }
            $cat_qty =  $aty;
        }


        return $cat_qty;
    }
```